# cut-elimination provable in PRA

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, proof-theory

What is the standard reference for the provability of the cut-elimination theorem in PRA?

Update: Rasmus Blanck has offered a reference for a system other than Gentzen's $\mathfrak L \mathfrak K$. The bounty is for a reference for the provability of the cut-elimination theorem for the sequent calculus $\mathfrak L \mathfrak K$ in PRA.

Comment: I don't have library resources where I am, so I can't verify the two suggestions by Not Mike and Rasmus before the bounty runs out. I am awarding a bounty to both answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My suggestion is Theorem 5.17 in section V.5.(d) of Hájek and Pudlák's *Metamathematics of First-Order Arithmetic*, Springer-Verlag, 1993. There, cut-elimination is shown to be provable in the even weaker theory $I\Delta_0 + \text{superexp}$.

Comment: Hájek and Pudlák appear to formulate the cut-elimination theorem for a system substantially different from Gentzen's $\mathfrak L \mathfrak K$, and adapting their result to derivations in $\mathfrak L \mathfrak K$ looks like a bit of a chore. Can you suggest another source for derivations in $\mathfrak L \mathfrak K$, or a definitive statement linking the two systems?

Comment: Perhaps chapter 1 of *Handbook of Proof Theory* (edited by Samuel Buss, Elsevier, 1998), might be what you are looking for. Cut-elimination is discussed in section 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

I think the chapter "Proof Theory: Some Applications of Cut-Elimination", by Helmut Schwichtenberg, from "Handbook of Mathematical  Logic", might be what you are looking for.